# Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor "x" Tensor at layer "x" . The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a small network using some custom network boxes for each use case, It looks like this :

```
def top_block(dropout = None, training = None):
    
    # scaled input
    input_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,15), dtype='float32')
    input_2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,15), dtype='float32')
    
    if dropout:
        layer_one = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout)(input_1,   training = training)
        layer_two = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout)(input_2,   training = training)
        return [layer_one,layer_two]
    return [input_1,input_2]
    

def bottom_layer(input_layers):
    
    data = tf.reduce_mean(input_layers,0)
    cls_layer     = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                                              kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=200), 
                                              activation = 'sigmoid')(data)
    
    model         = tf.keras.Model([input_layers[0], input_layers[1]], cls_layer , name = 'model_1')
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

If I am trying to access this network without dropout, it's working fine :

```
top_          = top_block()
model         = bottom_layer(top_ )
```

But if I am accessing with dropout, it's giving error:

```
top_          = top_block(dropout = 0.2, training = True)
model         = bottom_layer(top_ )
```

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_72:0", shape=(None, 1, 15), dtype=float32) at layer "input_72". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

1. How to access the model with dropout layer?
2. How to disable `training = False` during evaluate? Do I need to load full model and old model weights?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my input is coming from intermediate layer (dropout layer), It should come directly from Input layer :

```
def top_block():
    
    # scaled input
    input_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,15), dtype='float32')
    input_2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,15), dtype='float32')
    
    return [input_1, input_2]
    
def apply_dropout(layers_data, dropout_val, training):
    
    layer_one = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout_val)(layers_data[0],   training = training)
    layer_two = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = dropout_val)(layers_data[1],   training = training)
    return [layer_one, layer_two]

def bottom_layer(input_layers, data):
    
    data = tf.reduce_mean(data, 0)
    cls_layer     = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,
                                              kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=200), 
                                              activation = 'sigmoid')(data)
    
    model         = tf.keras.Model(input_layers, cls_layer , name = 'model_1')
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

It's working now

```
top_          = top_block()
dropout_      = apply_dropout(top_, 0.2, True)
model         = bottom_layer(top_ , dropout_)
```